# Error: google cloud AutoML cannot import library

Tags: python, function, cloud, google-cloud-ml, automl

On google cloud, there are 2 parts done:
1- AutoML model to predict XOR gate output, data is trained, model is built and deployed and tested successfully.

2- To use this model, I created a new google python function, once I add the line:

```
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl
```

I got the following error:

```
Deployment failure:
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Detailed stack trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 315, in check_or_load_user_function
_function_handler.load_user_function()
File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker_v1.py", line 190, in load_user_function
spec.loader.exec_module(main_module)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/user_code/main.py", line 2, in <module>
from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl
ImportError: cannot import name 'automl_v1beta1' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I am following the procedure in the link:

- https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/predict

Is it an issue in the requirement.txt file ?  Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Is there another library should be used other than: "from google.cloud import automl_v1beta1 as automl"

Answer (score 1):

in the requirements.txt I added the following line:
google-cloud-automl